# Using js to set height of one div to the same height as another div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to set the height of a div to the same height as another div using this

```
var aboutheight=document.getElementById('about').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('sampledogs').setAttribute("style","height:aboutheight");
```

But the height stays the same!
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like jQuery for this problem its simple and easy to read:

```
$('#sampledogs').height($('#about').height());
```

I find enough uses for jquery simplicity to include it in just about any project using javascript that I do.  Makes working with the DOM much easier.

Comment: @user2620338 any time

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript ain't inserting variables in strings. You need to concat it:

```
document.getElementById('sampledogs').setAttribute("style", "height:" + aboutheight);
// or better
document.getElementById('sampledogs').style.height = aboutheight;
```

Comment: for some reason neither worked for me, i accepted the jquery answer above............